# How to solve a #N/A or #VALUE! that should not occur as a result of a VLOOKUP in excel 2016 since the searched value exists?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have several `VLOOKUP` that returns `#N/A` or `#VALUE!` even when the searched value is in the lookup range. For many lines, they return the expected value.

For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A26;'TAB2'!$AA$2:$AI$784;7;FALSE)
A26 = 22
'TAB2'!$AA$97 = 22
```

- The fourth argument of VLOOKUP is always FALSE
- The searched value is indirect, but the value in the cell is a value, not a formula, though both should work
- If I test with the example above `= A26 = 'TAB2'!$AA$97`, the result is `TRUE`

If I try to reproduce a minimal example, I cannot. Any idea please?

Comment: what does `The searched value is indirect, but the value in the cell is a value, not a formula, though both should work` mean?  Is your formula above different, if so how?  show the actual formula.

Comment: possibly a type mismatch where one is a text and the other is a number. Or possibly the number being pulled is calculated and so may not be exactly 22...

Comment: Better share some sample data along with the formula U have used do far,, !

Comment: @Scott the indirection is only `A26 = 22`

Comment: @gris I checked the data types, only integers which are not calculated

Comment: @gris Anyway, I could check that if you put the same number, say 22, in two cells `A1` and `A2`, then change the format of one to be `text` and the other to be a `number`, then an equality such as `=A1=A2` returns TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I did insert a column before the one defined to return the VLOOKUP result (7th one), then I was pointing to a wrong column containing errors, but quite with the same data which made the root cause hard to find.